# How to Push Data From one WKInterfaceController to Another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, wkinterfacelabel

I have 2 Interface Controllers in my WatchKit.  The first one is called InterfaceController while the other is called DetailsForWatch.  IC has a tableView on it.  It parses data from a Parse class, and displays data from each entry in the class as a row. This works fine.

What I am trying to do is pass the PFObject for the selected row to a PFObject in DetailsForWatch.  My setup for DFW is:

.h

```
@interface DetailsForWatch : WKInterfaceController {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *detailsLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFObject *finalObject;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    NSString *details = self.finalObject [@"Request"];

    [self.detailsLabel setText:details];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.finalObject);
    // Configure interface objects here.
}
```

In IC, for .h I have:

```
@class DetailsForWatch;
@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController {
    DetailsForWatch *_theDetails;


}
@property (retain) DetailsForWatch *theDetails;
@end
```

In the .m I have:

```
@synthesize theDetails = _theDetails;
```

for didSelectRowAtIndex, I have:

```
_theObject = _theObjective[rowIndex];

    self.theDetails = [[DetailsForWatch alloc] init];
    _theDetails.finalObject = _theObject;
```

I set up the DFW as a Push selection from the Group on IC.  When I select a row in the IC, it pushes a blank screen, and the NSLog shows that the PFObject named finalObject is (null).  What am I doing wrong that it is not passing on PFObject properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to pass data between the two interface controllers.  The way I have been doing it is like this:

1. create a segue (give it an identifier if necessary) between the two controllers in my storyboard.
2. In interface controller 1 implement

`- (id)contextForSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier`

it will be called when the segue is triggered via button press or whatever.

This can return any object such as a dictionary of the data (in your case 'theDetails')

3. In interface controller 2 implement

`- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context`

the context object here will be the one you passed through in controller 1